# Customization of tracking code

Tags: javascript

i am new here and i have a javascript tracking code

```
 var _trackingCode = '5sulid5e';
(function() {
    var wa = document.createElement('script');
    wa.type = 'text/javascript';
    wa.async = true;
    wa.src = '//cdn.8digits.com/automation.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wa, s);
})();
```

i want to customize that for work on another website. 
it works on vestel.com.tr but it doesnt work on mavi.com . 
How can i customize that script for mavicom. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should ask the vendor (8digits?) or look in their documentation. I suspect the `_trackingCode` is associated in their system with the original domain name, so you probably need to get another tracking code for the new domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can hack this by writing a proxy, as some vendors may bind tracking IDs with a specific domain.

Forward the ajax from the vendor's JS code to your proxy server. In your proxy server modify the origin request header as the registered header i.e. vestel.com.tr .For this you will need to modify the JS code provided by vendor located at cdn.8digits.com/automation.js and then in script tag of your website provide the script source as your hacked JS, NOT the actual one.

PS you can't modify the origin header in the browser's AJAX itself due to security restriction by browsers.